# Is window.document.height deprecated in Chrome 17?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I just updated to the latest version of Chrome (17.0.963.56) and it appears that window.document.height is no longer a valid property. Has anyone else noticed this? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding it's removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filing a bug with WebKit, I was informed that `document.height`
isn't a standard property and WebKit was the only vendor maintaining
support for it (until now.) Both MDN and WebKit now list the
properties as deprecated and suggest using
`document.body.clientHeight` or `document.body.clientWidth` instead of
`document.width` or `document/height`.

Comment: document.body.clientHeight is hardly the same, it returns an even smaller number than waht I am after .. ( setTimeout returns something else 100 ms later )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, `window.innerHeight` works for me.
[docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)